# How to install SVN v. 1.6.11 in RHEL 7

Tags: svn, rhel7

Im new in Linux server and I don't have any idea how can I install SVN v1.6.11 in RHEL7. Can you guys help me?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You must not use SVN 1.7 or older versions. They are very outdated, not supported and do not receive security and bug fixes.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have the `rhel-7-server-rpms` repository enabled first. This happens automatically when you subscribe with Red Hat Subscription Manager, which requires you to have a valid subscription.

The latest version available is 1.7.14 via the `subversion` package, and can be installed with this command:

```
sudo yum install subversion
```

**Edit:** Subversion 1.6.11 is only available for RHEL 6.

Comment: So is there a way to install this SVN 1.6.11?

Comment: No, there are no plans to rebase svn for RHEL 6. The highest version available is 1.6.11. There are issues with upgrading because of changes to the local working copy between svn 1.6 and 1.7.